# Does blue light cause stomata to open or close?

Tags: plant-physiology, photosynthesis

In my biology lecture notes, it says that blue light causes stomata to close.

But thinking about it logically, since plants absorb a high percentage of blue light compared to light at other wavelengths, so wouldn't it cause stomata to open?